# Разделить поровну на экране

Tags: android, android-layout

Не понимаю как разделить экран на равные части. Вот у меня есть 7 элементов, как разделить для них экран поровну, пробовал через массы, но почему-то не срабатывает.

```
<android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout
    xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    >
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_gravity = "bottom"
    app:cardBackgroundColor = "@color/blue2"
    app:cardCornerRadius = "6dp"
    app:cardElevation = "0dp"
    app:layout_aspectRatio = "100%"
    app:layout_widthPercent = "100%"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <TextView
            android:id = "@+id/lvl_tank"
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity = "center"
            android:text = "000"
            android:textColor = "@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/tank"
            android:id="@+id/ImageTank"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id = "@+id/name_tank"
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity = "center"
            android:text = "name_tank"
            android:textColor = "@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id = "@+id/boi"
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity = "center"
            android:text = "boi"
            android:textColor = "@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id = "@+id/wins"
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity = "center"
            android:text = "wins"
            android:textColor = "@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id = "@+id/crednie_damage"
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity = "center"
            android:text = "cred_dm"
            android:textColor = "@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_weight="1" />


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout>
```

Comment: вы уж выберете что то одно - percent (проценты) - PercentRelativeLayout (а не PercentFrameLayout) или weight (веса)и LinearLayout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вашу задачу можно решить, например, с помощью атрибута `layout_weight`.

Приведу простой пример. Допустим, необходимо поровну разделить пространство (по ширине) между тремя `TextView`. Реализуется это так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Размеры виджетов, вложенных в `LinearLayout`, вычисляются в два этапа: на первом этапе используются значения атрибутов `layout_width` и `layout_height`, а на втором этапе осуществляется распределение оставшегося свободного пространства между виджетами (согласно атрибуту `layout_weight`).

Указав `layout_width="0dp"` Вы фактически пропускаете первый этап и размеры виджетов определяются только исходя из атрибута `layout_weight`. Так как значение атрибута `layout_weight` у всех трех `TextView` одинаково, то свободное пространство будет распределено равномерно между этими тремя виджетами.

Если, например, второму `TextView` задать `layout_weight="5"`, то сумма весов будет `1+5+1=7` и первому `TextView` будет отдано `1/7` всей ширины, второму – `5/7`, а третьему – `1/7`.