# Как сделать, чтобы textView не перекрывали друг-друга?

Tags: android, xml, textview

У меня есть три textView, которые я хочу выровнить по левому краю, по центру и справа соответственно. Проблема в том, что если текст слишком большой, то они начинают залезать друг на друга(см. скрин). Как это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один из вариантов решения, это использования весов. Для этого у родителя нужно указать  `android:weightSum ="4"` - это общая сумма под элементов(можно не указывать, если все элементы имеют размер веса).
У TextView указать его вес (например) `android:layout_weight="2"`, а так же указать `android:layout_width="0dp"`. А так можете посмотреть еще  [Тут более наглядно показано](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/656195/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5).

Вот не большой пример. Где  у меня первый `TextView` весом 2, и два других весом 1. (2 + 1 + 1). Значит первый будет занимать половину размера родителя, и два других по четверти

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum ="4"> //Если указаны во всех подэлементов весы, не обязательно

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nickname_textView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="Никнэйм" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/battles_textView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Бои"
            android:textAlignment="viewEnd" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wins_textView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Победы"
            android:textAlignment="viewEnd" />
    </TableRow>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы, исправил ошибку

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!

Comment: лучше вам исправить сам код разметки и как то объяснить, как в LinearLayot попал компонент TableLayout и для чего он там. Я, например, вообще не уверен, что такая разметка пройдет инфлейт

Comment: Дело в том что я у себя использую несколько TableRow в этой разметки(каждая имеет разное количество элементов). Есть более правильный способ размещать элементы?

Comment: Дело в том, что в данной разметке компонент `TableRow` как минимум абсолютно лишний и ничего, кроме дополнительной нагрузки на устройство не дает, а вообще он принадлежит контейнеру `TableLayout`, а не `LinearLayout`. По сути `TableLayout` представляет собой вертикальный `LinearLayout`, а `TableRow` - горизонтальный `LinearLayout` с несколькими дополнительными атрибутами форматирования таблицы. Для верстки структуры таблицы этот контейнер наиболее подходит, но не в этом примере. В вашем ответе ссылка на другой ответ, в нем вполне коректная разметка, объясняющая использование весов элементов.

Comment: То есть, правильно в данном случае, корневому `LinearLayout` указать атрибут `horizontal` и ему же указывать сумму весов, если требуется, а `TableRow` совсем исключить.

Comment: да я вас понял, я брал пример по большей части из-за скриншота, поэтому не делал через LinearLayout